# How could I align vertically my registration form on the site?

Tags: html, css

I created simple registration form based on the bootstrap framework, that will be integrated into the site:

```
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <center><h2>Регистрационная форма</h2></center>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method='post' action='/contact.php' id='form'>
        <fieldset class="myfields">
        <div><label>Name: </label><input type='text' name='name' required id='name'></div>
        <div><label>Surname: </label><input type='text' name='surname' required id='surname'></div>
        <div> <label>Mail: </label><input type='email' name='email' required id='email'></div>
        <div><label>Phone: </label><input type='text' name='phone' required id='phone'></div>
        <div><label>Skype: </label><input type='text' name='skype' required id='skype'></div>
        <div><label>Assess: </label><select name='assistance' id='assistance'>
            <option value='With first parameter'>One</option>
            <option value='With second parameter'>Two</option>
        </select></div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary"  type='submit' value='Send'>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

and this CSS configuration:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .myfields label, .myfields input, .myfields select {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    }
    form {
    text-align:center;
    }
    .myfields label, .myfields select {
    text-align:left;
    width:100px;
    }

    .myfields select {
    text-align:left;
    width:200px;
    }

    .myfields input {
    width:200px;
    }
</style>
```

How could I middle my registration block in the vertical center of the page? vertical-align doesn't work in this case :-(
It may be java-script or CSS solution, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your page contents in a `<div>` with an id of **container** and apply the following CSS:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 400px; /* big enough to wrap around the entire contents */
    margin-top: -200px; /* -(this.height / 2) */
}
```

The theory is that you "bump" the div down the page 50% and then shift it back up the page with a negative margin equal to half the height.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/AfNgu/2/

Comment: Why does it have to be absolute?

Comment: @rps because `top` won't be applied if `relative` and if we use `fixed` then it could be unusable on a smaller viewport (i.e. if the vertical resolution is under the container height)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

Setting `margin:0px auto;` and `width:400px;`(you can play with it until it's center) on the div tag `id="main"` will center the entire section. I gave the `fieldset` a `width` as well

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pUQQr/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="w1">
    <div class="w2">
        <center><h2>Регистрационная форма</h2></center>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method='post' action='/contact.php' id='form'>
            <fieldset class="myfields">
            <div><label>Name: </label><input type='text' name='name' required id='name'></div>
            <div><label>Surname: </label><input type='text' name='surname' required id='surname'></div>
            <div> <label>Mail: </label><input type='email' name='email' required id='email'></div>
            <div><label>Phone: </label><input type='text' name='phone' required id='phone'></div>
            <div><label>Skype: </label><input type='text' name='skype' required id='skype'></div>
            <div><label>Assess: </label><select name='assistance' id='assistance'>
                <option value='With first parameter'>One</option>
                <option value='With second parameter'>Two</option>
            </select></div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary"  type='submit' value='Send'>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,body{height: 100%;}
    body{margin: 0;}
    .w1{
        min-height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .w1:after{
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        min-height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 1px;
    }
    .w2{
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .myfields label, .myfields input, .myfields select {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    }
    form {
    text-align:center;
    }
    .myfields label, .myfields select {
    text-align:left;
    width:100px;
    }

    .myfields select {
    text-align:left;
    width:200px;
    }

    .myfields input {
    width:200px;
    }
```